# How can I change the style of a specific item within ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to list a bunch of dish postings on my website and I want to open a modal when I click on it (this modal will have access to the data for that dish).  To do this I am trying to give each dish a modal div with its own id (dish-$index), and then changing the style of the modal from display:none to display: block.  For some reason I can't get element by Id dish-{{$index}} in my javascript (it returns null).  Why doesn't this work or what is a better way to do this?  I don't want to use bootstrap.

```
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button class="order">Open Modal</button>

        <div id="dish-{{$index}}" class="modal4">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content4">
            {{dish.dishName}}

            <span class="close4">x</span>
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

```
var selector = 'div[ng-id="' + child.key + '"]';
var modal4 = document.getElementById("dish-{{$index}}");
var span4 = document.getElementsByClassName("close4")[0];

$('body').on('click', selector, function () {
     google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click', {});
     modal4.style.display = "block";
                });
```

Comment: Can yo add any Fiddle/Plnkr?

Comment: one possible reason could be $index is not present in your java-script scope.

Answer (score 1):

You try to use the Angular interpolation in Javascript (`document.getElementById("dish-{{$index}}");`). This will not work.

Instead of register a on-click event with jQuery you could use the angular directive ng-click. I assume all your dishes are saved in an array of javascript objects.

```
<div ng-repeat="dish in dishes">
   <button class="order" ng-click="dish.modalVisible = true">Open Modal</button>

    <div id="dish-{{$index}}" class="modal4">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content4" ng-if="dish.visible">
        {{dish.dishName}}

        <span class="close4" ng-click="dish.modalVisible = false">x</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

The directive ng-if insert the HTML of that element only then into the DOM when the condition evaluates to a true value. With help of the first ng-click we set the modalVisible property to true. The the modal get rendered. The ng-click on the close button set modalVisible to false and the modal gets removed out of the DOM. You could also use ng-show instead of ng-if. This only hides the element but remaining in the DOM.

You could look into the documentation on the angular site:

- [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)
- [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)